# Using tuples, case classes to better abstract a data structure

Tags: scala

I'm reading the following input:

```
0 3
4 6
6 7
3 5
0 7
```

Each row represents a test case (numbers represent indices).

I have another array of values that match to the indices in the test case.

```
val widthValues = List(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3)
```

The desired result is finding the minimum width value from a spliced array based on the index range in the test case.

e.g. test case `"0 3"`  returns `1` as the `min` of `List(2, 3, 1, 2)` which is `widthValues` from index `0` to `3`.

I currently have this

```
    val widthValues = List(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3)
    val in = stdin.getLines
    for(testCase <- in) {  
         val case = testCase.split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList 
         println(widthValues.slice(case(0), case(1)).min)
    }
```

I'd rather abstract the structure a little further though, maybe using tuples?   case classes?   to represent the range as (i, j).   like a list of tuples(i, j)??  I'm not sure.

There's got to be a better way of doing this, and I'm not sure what Scala tricks I  need to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more scalable approach,

```
class Interval(a: Int, b: Int) {
  def apply(xs: List[Int]) = xs.slice(a,b)
}

object Interval {
  def apply(s: String) = {
    val Array(a,b) = s.split("\\s+").map(_.toInt)
    new Interval(a,b)
  }
}
```

Use it as follows,

```
val intervals = testcases.map(Interval(_))
val allLeast = intervals.map(_(widthValues).min)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly better way

```
val Array(idx1,idx2) = testCase.split(" ").map(_.toInt) 
println(widthValues.slice(idx1, idx2).min)
```

This allows you to use meaningful variable names instead of `case(0)`

If you plan to store those further, I would suggest using case class, such as

```
case class TestCase( idx1: Int, idx2: Int )
```

Answer (score 1):

@eugener has shown you the shortest solution (IMO). If you would like a solution that abstracts the range more (assuming you work in a larger setting). Consider using Scala's `Range` class:

```
val Array(lo, hi) = testCase.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
val range = lo to hi
println(widthValues.slice(range.start, range.end).min)
```

Of course, this is only useful if you pass it around. Otherwise just using the indices directly is probably better.

Comment: interesting.  the documention for Range uses the "until" keyword.   Is that any different than "to?"

Comment: Yes. `to` is inclusive, `until` is exclusive.